# Spring Beans with same ids in different config files not getting correctly autowired

Tags: xml, spring

Have multiple applicationcontexts which get loaded in Spring.

Have two beans of same ids but different types in different contexts that get loaded suppose-
application1.xml

```
<bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.one.EmployeeDAO" />
```

application2.xml

```
<bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.two.EmployeeDAO" />
```

Have a constructor in another config file as follows-
application3.xml

```
<bean id="employeeService" class="com.one.EmployeeService">
        <constructor-arg ref="employeeDAO" />
    </bean>
```

this expects a bean of type **com.one.EmployeeDAO**.

The application flow is-

1. Initially application1.xml gets loaded and com.one.EmployeeDAO bean gets created.
2. Then application2.xml which creates the com.one.EmployeeService bean.
3. Then application3.xml which creates the com.two.EmployeeDAO bean.

Now in another config file application4.xml when I try to import application2.xml get the following exception-

**org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService' defined in class path resource [application2.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.one.EmployeeService]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [com.two.EmployeeDAO] to required type [com.one.EmployeeDAO]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found**

Comment: Spring is trying to inject your `com.two` DAO into a service that has a constructor that only accepts a `com.one` DAO because your application2.xml has overridden the bean id from application1.xml (i assume). Generally in spring, you cannot have multiple spring-beans with the same ID. I don't know how your spring application isnt throwing exceptions about duplicate bean-ids instead.

Comment: I think if the beans with same id are in different config files it works good. For example beanId1 in application1.xml. In application2.xml also there is beanId1. And we import application2.xml in application1.xml, there is no exception of duplicate bean.

Comment: Yeah it seems like it. The case is still that spring just overrides the old bean with the new one, when the bean id has been specified multiple times. (the latter will win, dependency-injection wise).